# Errors not ignored in Start-Job InitializationScript

Tags: powershell

I have a script module whose .psm1 file runs a command that will fail if a certain registry value is not present.  I want to ignore this failure, so the .psm1 script runs the command as:

```
CommandThatMayFail -ea SilentlyContinue
```

This works just fine when I import the module in a PowerShell session.  But one of the functions in this module starts some PS Jobs that also require the module to be imported.  When I import the module in the job's InitializationScript the failures from CommandThatMayFail are not ignored and the job terminates.  I tried wrapping CommandThatMayFail in a Try/Catch block, but that didn't help any.

I have avoided the problem by importing the module in the job's ScriptBlock instead of the InitializationScript.  But I am still curious about what is going on here.  Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a trap in the same scope as the InitializationScript but PRECEDING it in the code:

```
Trap{
    <commands you want it to run in case of error>;
    continue
    }
```

The important part there is the semicolon and the `continue`.  I had the same issue today, ironically enough, and this fixed it for me.  I think it's an issue with terminating/non terminating errors and scopes but this is the only way I could resolve it in my own script.

Comment: Trap didn't work any better than try/catch (as I had expected).  It looks to me like PowerShell fails the job if any non-terminating errors occur in the InitializationScript.